# How to remove a text from the StatusBar using React-Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I have a problem with this code:

```
<Tab.Navigator
      shifting={false}
      barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: home ? '#000' : '#fff',
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor={home ? '#fff' : '#000'}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        listeners={{
          focus: () => setHome(true),
          blur: () => setHome(false),
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="home" size={24} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Discover"
        component={Discover}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Discover',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <AntDesign name="search1" size={24} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
```

I try to remove the name "Home" and "Discover". I just want to see the icon. If I remove `tabBarLabel: 'Discover',`  nothing happens, but if I try this : `tabBarLabel: '',` does not show up anymore, instead I have a space there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `showLabel` as false on `Tab.Navigator`. [See the doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#showlabel)

Something like this:

```jsx
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={{
    showLabel: false
  }}
>
```